# load content and show one by one php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    function getfilter(str){
        if (str==""){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "Views/pfolioresult.php?q="+str,
            type: "GET",
            //  data: serializedData,
            success: function ( responseText ) {
                $("#result").html(responseText); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code works correctly. But suppose I have 10,000 data in database. This code show all data at once after loading. How is it possible to show data one by one depending on load time. That means when one item is loaded then show it, and other continuously show.

Comment: it is not possible like that... you can have a look at the various infinite scroll plugins available for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Some idea, on how this could be done:

```
function show(skip)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "Views/pfolioresult.php?skip=" + skip + "q="+str,
        type: "GET",
    //  data: serializedData,
        success: function ( responseText ) {
    $("#result").html(responseText); 
            skip++;
            show(skip);
        }
    });
}

show(0);
```

and your query in php should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LIMIT $skip, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pagination and then load content on some event like scrolling or clicking of a lable saying "load more". It is not a good idea to load all records at once.

`url: "Views/pfolioresult.php?q="+str+"&page=0&limit=10",`

And then in your query you can use `page` and `limit` like

```
$sql = "SELECT ....";

$limit = $_POST['page'] * $_POST['limit']; // get offset records

$sql .= " limit {$limit}, {$_POST['limit']}";
```

When loading more records like page 2 you can set `page=1` in ajax url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show that way, you should split the response and show one by one or batch by batch, but this will lead to confusion. which is not a good idea. Better to use plugins like jscroll or inifinite scroll with paging system which will reduce the response time, so that app will work faster and you can achieve what you wanted.

Comment: so give some example uses code  with plugin link @Bala

Comment: if you see the example here http://jscroll.com/ this will load the next page through ajax. For you requirement you should call the same page passing extra query string like page no like 1/2/3 on each call incrementing, your backend code will read the page query string and gives response based on that.

Comment: you have to make changes both on js and back end code to achieve this.